# gitolite + gitweb | 'repo @all R = gitweb' not working

Tags: gitolite, gitweb

For some reason the following gitolite.conf does not add any repository to projects.list.
When I set 'R = gitweb' for each repository manually, they get added to projects.list.

```
[....]

repo aaa
repo bbb

repo @all
    RW+ = @admins
    R = gitweb

[...]
```

Any hints for me? I'd really like to allow gitweb access to all repositories and then remove permissions for a single repositories via '- = gitweb' ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't actually need `gitweb` rules or `project.list` to be complete in [my gitweb setup](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L49-L93):
I only make sure I have a [`gitweb.conf.pl`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb.conf.pl.tpl) which:

- will be called by gitweb (through the [`gitweb_config.perl`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl) file, called if gitweb detects it exists)
- will [call gitolite](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb.conf.pl.tpl#L43) to see if the access to a repo can be granted or should be denied.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll just go that way then.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the similar problem, but the resolution was different :

In gitolite3, it seems that if you simply see a gitweb.* property, then your repository is gitweb enabled:

```
repo foobar
  desc = "Foobar repository"
  category = "foobar"
  Rw+= myself
```

Or if you prefer :

```
repo foobar
  config gitweb.description = "Foobar repository"
  config gitweb.category = "foobar"
  Rw+= myself
```

I don't know if it works with a @all, like:

```
repo @all
  category= "uncategorized"
```

But since a description or (valid) category is not a bad thing to have, I'd say it works for me.

On the other hand, I tried also making an @almost-all group with all my repositories except gitolite-admin, except I don't know if it works because of gitweb.description/category config.