# Is it necessary to install gitweb?

Tags: git, gitolite, gitweb

Is it necessary to install gitweb to the server or are there other ways to add gitweb with installed gitolite on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) is just an **[authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html)**, meaning it comes between your server (ssh or httpd) and git.

You don't need gitweb if you don't need to browse the content of the git repos with a web GUI.

But if you do, and you already have gitolite installed, *then* you would need to [make gitweb call gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777459/how-to-get-gitolite-gitweb-working-together/9783189#9783189), and [declare a gitweb category](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15315416/6309) (otherwise, your user could see the content of repos they are not supposed to access).

---

If you don't (need `gitweb`), Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), teaches "`make all`" to build `gitweb` or to avoid `gitweb`.

See [commit a35258c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a35258c62adf5c0e591f2335f3427434ff0b63f0), [commit affc3b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/affc3b755cb4d1ac87096bbb93f5f2e57b703894), [commit 27438ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27438ef5e043ebca6336274c5b4e79287749eca6), [commit b82d66e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b82d66eb0cf840a991ff906ab4679785eae4605a), [commit 564ebde](https://github.com/git/git/commit/564ebde3d323fc3b22534dcbb32723807771b955), [commit 1e08fa5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e08fa5e2bf9cd254a742a0ac3e950a12fc45915), [commit 7decdb9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7decdb9b4ac322158069645685b7527cba65a7e7) (28 Jun 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
See [commit d3b8274](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3b827408c5a1148d7c7ec46d07380c31b0796e7) (28 Jun 2022) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 48e88a4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48e88a4862f3f0353f7a795dae0346dca0043829), 18 Jul 2022)</sup>

> ### [`gitweb/Makefile`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a35258c62adf5c0e591f2335f3427434ff0b63f0): add a `"NO_GITWEB"` parameter
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> From looking at the {Free,Net,Dragonfly}BSD packages for Git, they've been monkeypatching "`gitweb`" *out* of the `Makefile`, let's be nicer and provide a `NO_GITWEB=Y` for their use.
>
> For the "all" target this allows for optionally restoring what's been the status quo before the preceding commit, but now we'll also behave correctly on the subsequent "`make install`".
>
> As before our installation of `gitweb` can be suppressed with `NO_PERL`.
> For backwards compatibility the `NO_PERL=Y` flag by itself still doesn't change whether or not we build `gitweb`, unlike the new `NO_GITWEB=Y` flag.

And

> ### [`gitweb/Makefile`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/affc3b755cb4d1ac87096bbb93f5f2e57b703894): include in top-level `Makefile`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Include the `gitweb/Makefile` in the top-level `Makefile` rather than calling it as a sub-`Makefile`.
> As noted in the thread [starting at here](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20220525205651.825669-1-szeder.dev@gmail.com/) (in [particular here](https://lore.kernel.org/git/220526.86k0a96sv2.gmgdl@evledraar.gmail.com/)) we'll pay a high cost on `NOOP` runs of "`make`" just to figure out that we have nothing to do for "`make gitweb`".
>
> The "`gitweb`" script also isn't maintained out-of-tree, unlike "`gitk-git`" or "`git-gui`", which both have their own "`Makefile`".
> Other parts of it are already integrated into our main Makefiles, e.g. the documentation is built by `Documentation/Makefile` since [07ea4df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/07ea4df2780663aa851b7f7177d09ab63d1441bb) ("`gitweb`: Add gitweb(1) manpage for `gitweb` itself", 2011-10-16, Git v1.7.8-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/380f26c29ba8b32c0f4e450c9a6c48e24e0919da)).

Comment: Where should I add the gitweb.conf.pl and gitweb_config.perl to the server? Does your method involve not installing gitweb to the server, right? Thanks!

Comment: @user2955550 I like to put them in a dedicated folder, with symlinks to the gitweb.cgi script which is part of any git distribution. See https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/tree/master/gitweb. Then I call the script by referring to that dedicated folder in httpd.conf file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9783189/6309 (`DocumentRoot /path/to/gitweb` and `DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi`)

Comment: I didn't quite get why did you have this line "../usr/local/apps/git/share/gitweb " in: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb . I kinda actually need a web GUI. What processes are involved in web GUI? Does one need to create it or is it a part of git distribution? Did you use Apache as web server? Thanks!

Comment: @user2955550 gitweb is just a perl script which generates html representation of your repos. You need an http server (I used Apache httpd) to call that script and build your html pages.